# Is there a way to write a query to show in-line job data from a given date with any previous job data to follow?

Tags: mysql

I need to gather all jobs created yesterday from job table, joined with jobheader table by job-no.  From there I need to find the past three times we booked a job for the same i-no (Item#) and display the data in the same row as the job from yesterday.  If no previous jobs, the fields would be null (currently #NUM! because we're doing it manually in Excel).  If only one previous job, the pertinent fields would be populated and the rest null, and so on.

```
show CREATE TABLE job

job CREATE TABLE `job` (
`job-no` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
`j2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`fix-cost` double DEFAULT NULL,
`lab-cost` double DEFAULT NULL,
`mat-cost` double DEFAULT NULL,
`tot-cost` double DEFAULT NULL,
`var-cost` double DEFAULT NULL,
`create-date` date DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8    


show CREATE TABLE jobheader 

jobheader   CREATE TABLE `jobheader` (
`sdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
`qty` double DEFAULT NULL,
`tot-cost` double DEFAULT NULL,
`mat-cost` double DEFAULT NULL,
`lab-cost` double DEFAULT NULL,
`fix-cost` double DEFAULT NULL,
`var-cost` double DEFAULT NULL,
`i-no` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`j2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`job-no` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Here is the data from my tables:

```
job table:  
║sdate║qty║tot-cost ║mat-cost║lab-cost║fix-cost║var-cost║i-no        ║j2║job-no║  
║NULL ║200║1297.6372║942.9434║140.078 ║117.781 ║96.8348 ║NEOIN77886NX║1 ║734701║  
║NULL ║250║1230.327 ║918.7153║123.0637║103.475 ║85.073  ║NEOIN77886NX║3 ║762822║  
║NULL ║200║2346.3662║1283.929║515.1117║177.2188║370.1067║MEDV25653   ║0 ║786993║  
║NULL ║500║1065.5539║886.2611║70.8075 ║59.5367 ║48.9486 ║NEOIN77886NX║0 ║787041║  

jobheader table:  
║sdate║qty║tot-cost ║mat-cost║lab-cost║fix-cost║var-cost║i-no        ║j2║job-no║  
║NULL ║200║1297.6372║942.9434║140.078 ║117.781 ║96.8348 ║NEOIN77886NX║1 ║734701║  
║NULL ║250║1230.327 ║918.7153║123.0637║103.475 ║85.073  ║NEOIN77886NX║3 ║762822║  
║NULL ║200║2346.3662║1283.929║515.1117║177.2188║370.1067║MEDV25653   ║0 ║786993║  
║NULL ║500║1065.5539║886.2611║70.8075 ║59.5367 ║48.9486 ║NEOIN77886NX║0 ║787041║
```

Expected output (this is going to be messy because it's a lot of data).  I've also attached an image for a better representation of what I'm looking for.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTnrM.png):

```
║job-no║j2║create-date║i-no        ║qty║sdate║tot-cost║mat-cost║lab-cost║fix-cost║var-cost║job-no║j2║Qty║tot-cost║mat-cost║lab-cost║fix-cost║var-cost║job-no║j2║Qty║tot-cost ║mat-cost║lab-cost║fix-cost║var-cost║job-no║j2   ║Qty  ║tot-cost║mat-cost║lab-cost║fix-cost║var-cost║  
║787041║0 ║4/4/2019   ║NEOIN77886NX║200║     ║1,349.54║994.85  ║140.08  ║ 117.78 ║96.83   ║762822║3 ║250║1230.327║918.7153║123.0637║103.475 ║85.073  ║734701║1 ║200║1297.6372║942.9434║140.078 ║117.781 ║96.8348 ║#NUM! ║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!   ║#NUM!   ║#NUM!   ║#NUM!   ║#NUM!   ║  
║786993║0 ║4/4/2019   ║MEDV25653   ║200║     ║2,346.37║1,283.93║515.11  ║177.22  ║370.11  ║#NUM! ║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM! ║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║
```

Hopefully this explains things a little better, but isn't too much info.

Below is my query.  Eliminating the calculated fields for now, it runs without error, just gives me too many results for each of the jobs created yesterday.  I wrote these as subqueries so that I could limit the number of results, but I can't seem to figure out how to pass the jobh.i-no into the subqueries, thus not allowing me to limit the results.  If I can figure that out, and use LIMIT1, LIMIT1,1, and LIMIT 2,1 for each of my subqueries, I think this will produce what I'm looking for.  Any suggestions on how to change my query or how to pass on the Item# to the subqueries?

```
select

job.`job-no`,

job.`job-no2`,

job.`create-date`,

jobh.`i-no`,

jobh.qty,

jobh.`start-date`,

jobh.`std-tot-cost`,

jobh.`std-mat-cost`,

jobh.`std-lab-cost`,

jobh.`std-fix-cost`,

jobh.`std-var-cost`,

tmp.`std-tot-cost` as PreviousJobStdTotCost,

tmp.`std-mat-cost` as PreviousJobStdMatCost,

tmp.`std-lab-cost` as PreviousJobStdLabCost,

tmp.`std-fix-cost` as PreviousJobStdFixCost,

tmp.`std-var-cost` as PreviousJobStdVarCost,

tmp2.`std-tot-cost` as PreviousJob2StdTotCost,

tmp2.`std-mat-cost` as PreviousJob2StdMaCost,

tmp2.`std-lab-cost` as PreviousJob2StdLabCost,

tmp2.`std-fix-cost` as PreviousJob2StdFixCost,

tmp2.`std-var-cost` as PreviousJob2StdVarCost,

tmp3.`std-tot-cost` as PreviousJob3StdTotCost,

tmp3.`std-mat-cost` as PreviousJob3StdMatCost,

tmp3.`std-lab-cost` as PreviousJob3StdLabCost,

tmp3.`std-fix-cost` as PreviousJob3StdFixCost,

tmp3.`std-var-cost` as PreviousJob3StdVarCost

from asi.job as job

left join asi.jobheader  as jobh on job.`job-no`=jobh.`job-no` and job.`job-no2`=jobh.`job-no2`

left join (select jobh1.`i-no`, jobh1.`job-no`, jobh1.`std-tot-cost`, jobh1.`std-mat-cost`, jobh1.`std-lab-cost`, jobh1.`std-fix-cost`, jobh1.`std-var-cost` from asi.jobheader as jobh1 order by jobh1.`job-no` desc) tmp on tmp.`i-no`=jobh.`i-no` and tmp.`job-no`jobh.`job-no`

left join (select jobh2.`i-no`, jobh2.`job-no`, jobh2.`std-tot-cost`, jobh2.`std-mat-cost`, jobh2.`std-lab-cost`, jobh2.`std-fix-cost`, jobh2.`std-var-cost` from asi.jobheader as jobh2 order by jobh2.`job-no` desc ) tmp2 on tmp2.`i-no`=tmp.`i-no` and tmp2.`job-no`tmp.`job-no`

left join (select jobh3.`i-no`, jobh3.`job-no`, jobh3.`std-tot-cost`, jobh3.`std-mat-cost`, jobh3.`std-lab-cost`, jobh3.`std-fix-cost`, jobh3.`std-var-cost` from asi.jobheader as jobh3 order by jobh3.`job-no` desc) tmp3 on tmp3.`i-no`=tmp2.`i-no` and tmp3.`job-no`tmp2.`job-no`

where asi.job.`create-date`="2019-04-04" and asi.job.`job-no` is not null and asi.job.`job-no`""
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results

Comment: Thanks @Raymond.  This article was very helpful.  New to posting in forums like this, so didn't want to post too much.  I will add the pertinent data tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: I tried to edit it a bit to make the data a bit clearer (although your expected results is still a bit wonky). Feel free to revert if you want to keep the original version.

Comment: I have added my query, which is almost what I need, just giving me too many results.

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this

```
SELECT Order#, OrderDate, Item#, Price, Price_1, Price_2, Price_3, 
100 * (Price - COALESCE(Price_1,0)) / Price AS Diff_1,
100 * (Price - COALESCE(Price_2,0)) / Price AS Diff_2,
100 * (Price - COALESCE(Price_3,0)) / Price AS Diff_3
FROM
(SELECT Order#, OrderDate, Item#, Price, 
(SELECT Price FROM Orders AS Ord WHERE Ord.Order# < Orders.Order# AND Ord.Item# = Orders.Item# ORDER BY Order# DESC LIMIT 1) AS Price_1,
(SELECT Price FROM Orders AS Ord WHERE Ord.Order# < Orders.Order# AND Ord.Item# = Orders.Item# ORDER BY Order# DESC LIMIT 2,1) AS Price_2,
(SELECT Price FROM Orders AS Ord WHERE Ord.Order# < Orders.Order# AND Ord.Item# = Orders.Item# ORDER BY Order# DESC LIMIT 3,1) AS Price_3
FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate = "2019-04-02"
ORDER BY Order#) AS TMP
```

Comment: Thanks @Ivo.  I believe i've simplified my problem too much.  I'll add all pertinent details to my question tonight or tomorrow to give a better representation of what I'm dealing with.